# updating a data object in nested array in mongodb by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array, find

i have a serious problem in updating my data . i have no idea how i can update a specific field in an object of an array in my document .

here is my Schema model :

```
var shiftSchema = new Schema({
Phone: String,
final: Boolean,
statusSH: String,
order: {
    startTime: String,
    finishTime: String,
    income: String,
    orders: [{
        stat: String,
        orderId: String,
        customerPhone: String,
        orderQuantity: String,
        orderCost: String,
        orderCondition: String,
        orderTag: String
    }]
}
});
```

when i use "find" it gives me the document and not just the object.

now how can i edit "stat" by finding "orderId" ?

Note that i do not have the index of the object that i want to update and i can just use "find"or "findOne".

i search all over the web and i couldn't find a good guide and example .

sorry for my bad english.

All tips will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run this query, to update the stat property:

```
shiftSchema.updateOne({
  'order.orders.orderId': 'id'
}, {
  '$set': {'order.orders.$.stat': 'newStatus'}
})
.then((result) => {
  console.log(result)
}, (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
```

---

You can see I used [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to access an element in the array and update it without specifying the position of the element (with index).

I also used [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) to replace the value of a field.

With just `find` or `findOne` you will not make the actual update.